# Google website translator causing html to break

Tags: jquery, html, google-translate

I'm using the [google translate API](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/add) and as I trigger the translation, it adds lots of `<font>` tags throughout my code causing a jquery slider plugin to break, since it is using the inner html to do its thing.

My question is: is there any way that I can choose any div/section to not be translated?

I believe that I could remove all `<font>` from the slider section, but that seems like a cheap fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just give `class="notranslate"`